# Falling Blocks on player touch - Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in unity for a school project. I'm stuck on this one part where I want a block to fall and be destroyed once a player has touched the block and moved to the next. Having so much trouble and would love some assistance.
The concept of what i'm aiming for can be seen here: http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-b-cubed

Comment: What is your problem actually? Checking whick cube is player standing on or making base cubes to fall?

Comment: I'm not real sure how to detect if the block was touch by the player, then if it has left that block for it to fall.

Comment: OnMouseDown in attached script of the block will definitely be a start.

Answer (score 0):

On each block, you'll need to attach a script which contains the `OnCollisionExit ()` method ([reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit.html)). Pass in the collision parameter (see reference) and use the collision info to confirm that the object leaving the collider is the player (eg tag the player with a player tag in the inspector and check the collision's collider's tag).

In this method, place your code for making the block fall.

Make sure you've added colliders to your objects so that they interact. If you run into problems, post back some code and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need to detect collision here. It is not neccessary. Just compare base cube position with player cube position in x,z plane (there should be only difference in Y-axis since player cube is over base cube). No need for collsions here. Than you attach script to all base cubes checking for playercube to hover other them (position check) and than on playercube next movement you attach rigidbody to basecube and destroy it after a second. Simple:)

**EDIT**

The code should look like this. More or less.

```
GameObject playerCube; //this is reference to Player object
bool playerEnter = false;
bool playerLeft = false;


void Start()
{
     playerCube = Gameoject.Find("PlayerCube"); // here you put the name of your player object as a string. Exactly as it is in the hierarchy
}

void Update()
{
if(playerCube.transform.position.x == transform.position.x && playerCube.transform.position.z == transform.position.z)
{
      playerEnter = true; // this checks if player stepped on the cube 
}
if((playerCube.transform.position.x != transform.position.x || playerCube.transform.position.z != transform.position.z) && playerEnter == true && playerLeft == false) //checks if player left the cube
{
 playerLeft = true; // we do this so the code below is executed only once
    gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>(); // ads rigidbody to your basecube
    Destroy(gameObject, 1.0f); //destroys baseCube after one second
}
```

I think that more or less that should do it. In the final game I probably would use coroutines for your task. Also you need to think how do you check if the cube already was destroyed, I mean how will your game detect if player can step on the next cube - does it exist or not?

**EDIT 2** 
Hard to tell what will work or not without your hierarchy, your code and knowing what do you want to have exactly. Study this code - it will work after some adjustments to your needs

Comment: What would that code look like? I have no clue where to begin.

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work!? How will the player's position know that it's the same as the floor's (cube) position?

Comment: Oops. There is mistake in the if() statement. Right now its checking exact position. Correcting

Comment: The player i want to touch the blocks is called Player, the blocks underneath the player is in an empty, each block is called Cube, Cube (1), Cube (2), e.t.c. An example of what i'd like is http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-b-cubed

Comment: Do change "PlayerCube" to "Player" and attach this script to every Cube